# Scroll through PowerPoint slides with the mousewheel

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, scrolling, mouse-wheel

At least before 2007, I was able to scroll the mouse-wheel in a PowerPoint being viewed in Normal mode, and expect one notch on the mouse-wheel would advance one slide. If the window was too vertically compact, so that I could see the top edge of the slide or the bottom edge, but not both, then I would understandably need to scroll the mouse-wheel two notches to get to the next slide. All very nice.

But with the beautiful ribbon there has come a bothersome degradation. I haven't checked 2019 yet, but at least up through 2016 it takes some special effort to be able to scroll directly between slides with the mouse-wheel. I'm looking at a PowerPoint window that is large enough that it automatically zooms to 120%. I scroll down one notch with my mouse-wheel, and while the scroll bar instantly goes all the way to the next slide's position, the slide display just nudges Slide 1 up a teense bit, so that the margin between the top of the slide and inside edge of the box is no longer equal to the margin below the bottom of the slide, but 1/3. Now if I scroll the mouse-wheel down another notch, I'll see the next slide.

I can stop this phenomenon when I make the window narrower, to the point that it has to shrink the slide I see in order to keep the whole thing visible with no margins smaller than so wide. But down to 119% is not enough - I still need to scroll twice in that case. Only when the size is 118% in a window that's tall enough to fit 120% (plus automatic minimal margins) does it start scrolling smoothly.

I notice that the arrow keys instantly navigate between slides, to the point that if you've zoomed in enough that you can't see the whole slide, a vertical arrow will not take you to the top or bottom of the current slide, but directly to the adjacent slide with the same vertical alignment. That is not the solution I want.

It's fine with me if the rolling the scroll wheel down a notch uncovers the bottom edge of the slide that was previously hidden, but it seems the rule is, a lower edge must have at least so many pixels of margin from the edge of the window before it can be dismissed. Is there a way to reduce that minimal margin to zero, or at least to the margin that is automatically maintained in the process of auto-zooming while I change the size of the window?

Comment: Are you looking for the "One screen at a time" option, found in *Control Panel > Mouse* in the Wheel tab? This would make every wheel notch into page scroll. But it wouldn't affect only PowerPoint.

Comment: @harrymc No, most other things are good the way they are, I just want to fine tune PowerPoint

Comment: The strange part is that with me PowerPoint scrolls a page for every notch, no matter how small I make its window. Could you post an example presentation?

Comment: Maybe this evening. If I understand you correctly, the problem may be with a setting I have chosen for every version of Office, on many PCs, with many versions of Windows, but you haven't.

Comment: Or the opposite : Something I do naturally and don't remember. Is your Office version an upgrade or a new install? (Mine is new.)

Comment: My Office is new